# What is the way proper way to use GTXiLib in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to use integrate GTXLib(https://cocoapods.org/pods/GTXiLib) in my swift testing project, I have installed the pod and convert it's library hooking code from objective-c to Swift, also I have modified my application code to generate some accessibility errors. But unfortunately I never get any failure after test run.

Now I am trying to figure out what I did wrong in my code so that the GTXilib is not catching any error. Here are the original code and converted code. It will be appreciated, if anybody please share your  experience related to that also if you find out any problem in my code.

## Objective-C code

```
// Include the GTXiLib umbrella header.

// Note that that is +setUp not -setUp
+ (void)setUp {
  [super setUp];

  // ... your other setup code (if any) comes here.

  // Create an array of checks to be installed.
  NSArray *checksToBeInstalled = @[
      [GTXChecksCollection checkForAXLabelPresent]
  ];

  // Install GTX on all tests in *this* test class.
  [GTXiLib installOnTestSuite:[GTXTestSuite suiteWithAllTestsInClass:self]
                       checks:checksToBeInstalled
            elementBlacklists:@[]];
}
```

## Swift code

```
override static func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        //let checksToBeInstalled: [GTXChecking] = GTXChecksCollection.allGTXChecks()
        let checksToBeInstalled: [GTXChecking] = [GTXChecksCollection.checkForAXLabelPresent()]
        let tmp = GTXTestSuite.init(allTestsIn: ExampleTests.self)
        GTXiLib.install(on: tmp ?? GTXTestSuite(), checks: checksToBeInstalled, elementBlacklists: [])
    }
```

Comment: Hey, can you find any solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, basically what happened to me was that GTXiLib just runs on XCTest running with the Host Application but not on XCUITest.

https://github.com/google/GTXiLib/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.

The missing link is that in your test case you have to create the view and add it to the keyWindow (make sure your view's fame is >0).

This is because the library uses the keyWindow as it's root object and then traverses its subviews to run the checks on.
https://github.com/google/GTXiLib/blob/d9161c0cefd07556cd97739fdc8862a2711bc1d3/Classes/GTXiLibCore.m#L159

```
  func testBadButton() {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32)
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    keyWindow?.addSubview(button)
  }
```

After adding it to the key window I was finally able to verify that GTXiLib was actually doing something. This is error this test gives me:

```
One or more elements FAILED the accessibility checks:
  <UIButton: 0x7f97c043e390; frame = (0 0; 32 32); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001e77780>>
    + Check "Accessibility label" failed, This element doesn’t have an accessibility label. All accessibility elements must have accessibility labels.
    + Check "Touch target size" failed, This element has a small touch target. All tappable elements must have a minimum touch target size of 44X44 points.



Element accessibilityFrame: 32x32.



Element frame: 32x32.


 (NSInternalInconsistencyException)
```

I would also recommend doing some type of window management to support these tests. In my case, I saw some accessibility failures because other objects in the window were being tested that were not the view I was interested in testing.

Final note: I ended up integrating [GTXiLib 3.1](https://github.com/google/GTXiLib/releases/tag/3.1.0) because newer versions depend on c++ which requires importing protobuf. There was an issue we encountered with protobuf not playing well with Carthage. May only be an issue with Carthage though since the Google team appears to be using Cocoapods.